# Why does Ubuntu not boot into a 3.4-Kernel?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, kernel

I just need to install kernel 3.4 (or higher stable version) on my machine (with 8GB RAM) running Ubuntu 11.10. I did the following steps:

1. I downloaded the following DEB files:

   ```
   linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb
   linux-headers-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_i386.deb
   linux-image-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_i386.deb
   ```
2. I installed them by,

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
3. I restarted the machine and I selected kernel 3.4 from GRUB menu. Ubuntu hangs there and never comes up (I waited for a few minutes...).

I have NVidia Graphic Card installed properly.

If I restart the computer and select kernel 3.0 from GRUB menu, it boots up normally without any problem. I don't know what is the problem, but I guess that I should find a way to install nVidia linux driver on kernel 3.4, but how I can do this while it gets stuck at boot up?

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade to 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

Maby try install a newer nvidia driver on your 3.0 kernel. When you update you kernel the driver will be rebuild.

Do this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go to your additional driver page and select the nvidia 310 driver.
Wait until the driver is installed.

Than update your kernel (it is important you install it again i think) and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when dual booting you go into the last OS installed to update GRUB or new kernels and such won't show up.